# ServiceStack - Route With Multiple DTO Layer

Tags: servicestack, routes

I have RequestDTO that have another DTO in that Class and it look like this:

```
[Route("/TheDtoRequest", "GET")]
[Route("/TheDtoRequest/{do_something_here_to_fill_foobar}", "GET")]
public class TheDtoRequest
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public FooBar Foobar { get; set; }
}


public class FooBar
{
    public string AnotherFoo {get; set;}
    public int AnotherBar {get; set;}
}
```

How I can Request with AnotherFoo parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate the `FooBar` parameter in your GET request to `/TheDtoRequest` using JSV format. You can learn about [JSV format here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Json-jsv-and-xml#wiki-jsv-text-format-json--csv). JSV Format (i.e. JSON-like Separated Values) is a JSON inspired format that uses CSV-style escaping for the least overhead and optimal performance.

> /TheDtoRequest?Foo=hello&Bar=1&FooBar={AnotherFoo:HelloWorld,AnotherBar:123}

So this query to the `/TheDtoRequest` route results in the class being populated. But you can also use JSV in routes. So given this route:

> /TheDtoRequest/{Foobar}

The query would result in the same populated object:

> /TheDtoRequest/{AnotherFoo:HelloWorld,AnotherBar:123}?Foo=hello&Bar=1

Or this route:

> /TheDtoRequest/{Foo}/{Bar}/{Foobar}
>
> /TheDtoRequest/hello/1/{AnotherFoo:HelloWorld,AnotherBar:123}

There is a good example of a [more complex object represented as JSV here](http://mono.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=176).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, That's Do The Tricks!! Btw, If i'm using directly like this: /TheDtoRequest/{AnotherFoo:HelloWorld,AnotherBar:123} it will throw you potentially dangerous Request.

Comment: @reptildarat That's an IIS error, you can turn that off. I didn't see that because I use the Self Hosted application. It should be safe enough to disable that check on the ServiceStack handled routes because it will parse the JSV, and should fine anything untoward. But glad it works.